# Using RSA (with openssl) in opposition to HTTPS

Tags: encryption, openssl, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am planning to implement API security in my REST application, Where i need work for authorization URL (on server PHP application) which will return a session token to client (mobile clients android, iphone, BB, wp7, wp8)requesting this url.

After looking for possible solutions i found these two perfect for my needs. but i am not able to decide on solution which will survive me on long runs.

1. Using RSA encryption with openssl for transferring user data to authorization URL (i am going with openssl just to stick with standard and secure method).
2. I have a hunch that it's possible to just use HTTPS to pass the user data and let OS handle encryption/decryption.

However, I am particularly inclined to first approach, since here client will not be able to make successful call to authorization url unless it has access to public key. But i am not sure about how well this approach will gel with all mobile clients.

Any help on this is much appreciated!..

Comment: OpenSSL uses RSA only for key exchange, the actual data is encrypted using symmetric cryptographic algorithms like AES (this is done for performance reasons). This a very common misconception.

Answer (score 0):

You should be ok when sending the authentication URL over SSL. SSL will authenticate the server and make sure that the data is protected against eavesdropping and man in the middle attacks. The URL will then be send over this protected channel, so after verifying the URL, the server can determine that the client is indeed the right entity. The token can then be safely send to the client over the same SSL session

If you go with your own scheme you will have to setup your own key management scheme and protocol. This is extremely hard to get right. Your comment on having access on a *public* key is a good indication that you will fail. SSL is not perfect either, but it has had a lot of scrutiny, and chances of it failing out of the blue are slim.

In other words, choose #2 over #1.